# Sharing non-serializable control objects between running applications in C#

Tags: c#, shared-memory

Is there a way to share non-serializable control object between two different applications.

I've used below code for sharing data among two applications, it is working fine.
My problem is that i need to share non-serializable objects between these applications.

## Application One

```
using (MemoryMappedFile mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateNew("testmap", 10000))
{
    bool mutexCreated;
    Mutex mutex = new Mutex(true, "testmapmutex", out mutexCreated);
    using (MemoryMappedViewStream stream = mmf.CreateViewStream())
    {
        BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(stream);
        writer.Write(1);
    }
    mutex.ReleaseMutex();

    string path = @"Second Application's path";

    //Run second application
    Process pr = new Process();
    ProcessStartInfo prs = new ProcessStartInfo();
    prs.FileName = path;
    pr.StartInfo = prs;
    bool ret = pr.Start();

    mutex.WaitOne();
    using (MemoryMappedViewStream stream = mmf.CreateViewStream())
    {
        BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(stream);
        MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Process A says: {0}", reader.ReadBoolean()));
        MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Process B says: {0}", reader.ReadBoolean()));
    }
    mutex.ReleaseMutex();
}
```

## Applicatin Second

```
try
{
    using (MemoryMappedFile mmf = MemoryMappedFile.OpenExisting("testmap"))
    {

        Mutex mutex = Mutex.OpenExisting("testmapmutex");
        mutex.WaitOne();

        using (MemoryMappedViewStream stream = mmf.CreateViewStream(1, 0))
        {
            BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(stream);
            writer.Write(0);
        }
        mutex.ReleaseMutex();
    }
}
catch (FileNotFoundException)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Memory-mapped file does not exist. Run Process A first.");
}
```

Can any one help me with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, memory mapped files cannot directly contain live managed objects.  There are two ways to use memory mapped files: using **MemoryMappedViewStream** (which our example is doing), or using **MemoryMappedViewAccessor**.  The latter lets you treat it as a big buffer of memory, reading and writing it with calls like **ReadDouble(offset)** and **Write(offset, doubleValue)**.  There are also accessor methods for reading and writing arrays.

Comment: Any example of `MemoryMappedViewAccessor`, or is there another way to share live objects between two applications.

Comment: A quick internet search found examples: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10806518/write-string-data-to-memorymappedfile) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedviewaccessor(v=vs.110).aspx). I'm sure there are more if you spend more time searching than I did.

Comment: I am not aware of a way to automatically share one instance of an CLR object between processes.  If you are really motivated, you could simulate sharing an object by writing a wrapper class that would use a shared memory mapped file to communicate updates between the instances that exist in each process.  If your information is complicated, this might be a lot of work.